# Error in reduceLeft in Map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to add key, value pairs in a `Map` using `reduceLeft()` but am getting a error. If I add the key value pair using `foldleft()` I get the right answer. What does this Error mean in `reduceLeft` and what is the correct code?

Code:

```
object Dcoder extends App
{
    var i = Map(1->2, 3->4, 5->6)
    var o = i.reduceLeft((a,b) => a._1 + b._1)
    println(o)
}
```

Error:

```
source_file.scala:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: (Int, Int)
var o=i.reduceLeft((a,b)=>a._1+b._1)
                          ^
one error found
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `fold` from one type to another but `reduce` is more restrictive. You can't reduce a collection of pairs, type `(Int,Int)`, to a single type `Int`.

This works by reducing a collection of pairs to a singe pair and then stripping away the 2nd element.

```
Map(1->2, 3->4, 5->6).reduceLeft(_._1 + _._1 -> 0)._1  //res0: Int = 9
```

Comment: To add to @jwvh's answer, you could also try just reducing the keys, eg.  `Map(1->2, 3->4, 5->6).keys.reduceLeft(_ + _)`. If you are just adding Ints, it's also generally better just to use `.sum` instead of `reduce`